# What directories do containers launched in Azure Container Instances have read access to?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-instances

My goal is to run a python script, which is passed to a docker container containing source code and dependencies. This is to be run using Azure container instances (ACI). On my home machine I can do this in docker (setting ENTRYPOINT or CMD to "python") with

```
docker run myimage "myscript.py"
```

provided I spin up the container from a directory containing `myscript.py`.

After some reading I thought a similar thing could be achieved on azure using `az container create --command-line` as indicated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/container-instances/container-instances-start-command). My container creation would be something like

```
az container create \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --name my-container \
  --image myimage:latest \
  --restart-policy Never \
  --command-line "python 'myscript.py'"
```

However the container is unable to find `myscript.py`. I am using the Azure Cloud Shell. I have tried spinning up the container from a directory containing `myscript.py`, and I have also tried adding a file share with `myscript.py` inside. In both cases I get the error

> python3: can't open file 'myscript.py': [Errno 2] No such file or
>   directory

I think I simply do not understand the containers and how they interact with the host directory structure on azure. Can anyone provide some suggestions or pointers to resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> provided I spin up the container from a directory containing
>   myscript.py.

From where you issue the command to start an container instance does not matter at all. The files need to be present inside your image. Or you can also [mount storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files) into it and read from there.

Comment: Thanks @silent! This was the nudge I apparently needed to understand the `--azure-file-volume-mount-path` option. I was successful when adding `--azure-file-volume-mount-path /mnt` (along with the other azure-file-volume flags) and ` --command-line "python /mnt/myscript.py"` to the container create command.